# HTML5 in Nokia N8

Tags: html, nokia

whether Nokia N8 native browser support HTML5?
I'm trying to displaying charts using HTML5 but its not working in Nokia N8 native browser.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect not. Formal spec is available here:

http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Web_Developers_Library/GUID-D5C6212A-5EF2-44BF-B1F0-650A5F57D501.html

and here:

http://yiibu.com/articles/practical-guide-to-nokia-browsers/